# how to implement 3d slider in angular 10

Tags: angular

I am pretty new to angular and I want to create a 3d carousel slider like [this](https://codepen.io/ksu/pen/NWKEoMp) in angular. How can I approach this problem?
please see the link for better presentation of the problem

```
function rotateLeft(){
  if(on == 0){
    $('.p_slider__item:nth-of-type(' + pos + ')').animate({'left':'200px'},200)
    $('.p_slider__item:nth-of-type(' + pos + ')').css('z-index','0')
    $('.p_slider__item:nth-of-type(' + pos2 + ')').animate({'left':'-200px'},200)
    setTimeout (function(){
      $('.p_slider__item:nth-of-type(' + pos2 + ')').css({'transform':'scale(0.6)','opacity':'0.8','webkit-filter':'blur(2px)','z-index':'1'});
      pos++;pos2++;pos3++;
      if(pos > 3){pos = 1}if(pos2 > 3){pos2 = 1;}if(pos3 > 3){pos3 = 1;}
    },400)
    $('.p_slider__item:nth-of-type(' + pos3 + ')').animate({'left':'0px'},200)
    $('.p_slider__item:nth-of-type(' + pos3 + ')').css({'transform':'scale(1)','opacity':'1','webkit-filter':'blur(0px)','z-index':'2'})
    setTimeout (function(){
      on = 0; // Accept clicks again
    },time)
  }
}
```

Comment: First of all, dont work with jquery in angular, dont manipulate the DOM by urself, its nto a good idea.
Use what angular gives u, its 10 times better and much easier.

Comment: thank you. I am looking for a way to convert the jquery code of the link into angular accepted structure

Comment: Found this for you but it's AngularJS : https://openbase.io/js/angular-carousel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

google is our friend, in [this David DeSandro's article](https://3dtransforms.desandro.com/carousel) you has all the "ingredients". Yes is css and javascript but you can easy translate to Angular

To get the cells we use viewChild and ViewChildren

```
  @ViewChild('carousel') carousel:ElementRef
  @ViewChildren('carousel__cell') cells:QueryList<ElementRef>
```

We need some auxiliars variables:

```
  selectedIndex = 0;
  cellWidth:number;
  cellHeight:number;
  isHorizontal:boolean = true;
  rotateFn = this.isHorizontal ? 'rotateY' : 'rotateX';
  radius:number
  theta:number;

  get cellCount()
  {
    return this.cells.length;
  }
```

Now create a function initCarousel

```
  initCarousel() {
    this.theta = 360 / this.cellCount;
    const cellSize = this.isHorizontal ? this.cellWidth : this.cellHeight;
    this.radius = Math.round( ( cellSize / 2) / Math.tan( Math.PI / this.cellCount ) );
    this.cells.forEach((cell:ElementRef,i:number)=>
    {
       if (i<this.cellCount)
       {
           cell.nativeElement.style.opacity=1
           const cellAngle=this.theta*i;
           cell.nativeElement.style.transform = this.rotateFn + '(' + cellAngle + 'deg) translateZ(' + this.radius + 'px)';
       }
       else
       {
        cell.nativeElement.style.opacity = 0;
        cell.nativeElement.style.transform = 'none';

       }
    })
    this.rotateCarousel();
  }
```

That we call in ngAfterViewInit

```
  ngAfterViewInit()
  {
    this.cellWidth = this.carousel.nativeElement.offsetWidth;
    this.cellHeight = this.carousel.nativeElement.offsetHeight;
    this.initCarousel()
  }
```

You can see in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-fh6hgt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

**Updated** Really the question is about a "pseudo-3d" and it's more easy. We need applied transform a scale and a position, so, we can has a function like

```
  getStyle(index:number)
  {
    if (!this.cellCount)
       return null;
    const angle=(index-this.selectedIndex)*2*Math.PI/this.cellCount
    const scale=((75)+25*Math.cos(angle))/100
    return {
      left:-75+150*Math.sin(angle)+'px',
      transform:'scale('+scale+')',
      position:'absolute',
      "z-index":Math.floor(100*scale)
    }
  }
```

And apply to a carousel

```
<div class="carousel" style="position:relative">
  <div *ngFor="let i of [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]" class="carousel__cell" 
     [ngStyle]="getStyle(i)">{{i}}
  </div>
</div>
```

**Update 2** using Angular animations. Well the last carousel it's looks like we want to achieve. For a particular case we can, e.g. has 9 positions defined and 3 images in position 0,2 and 7

in constructor inject AnimationBuilder

```
  constructor(private builder: AnimationBuilder) {}
```

And define as variables

```
  private player: AnimationPlayer;
  timer = 1000;
  animates = [0, 2, 7];
```

We define an auxiliar variable

```
  movements = [
    { pos: 0, right: [1, 2], left: [8, 7] },
    { pos: 2, right: [3, 4, 5, 6, 7], left: [1, 0] },
    { pos: 7, right: [8, 0], left: [6, 5, 4, 3, 2] }
  ];
```

The idea is create manually animations, so if e.g. one element is in pos=0 and we click 'right' we create 2 animations to reach the positions 1,2

Is a few complex the function, I put comments

```
  animateViews(direction: string) {
    //with each element of the array [0,2,7]
    this.animates.forEach((x: number, index: number) => {
      //get the item and the mov
      const mov = this.movements.find(m => m.pos == x);
      const item = this.itemsView.find((_x, i) => i == index);

      //create an array of animations
        const animations = mov[direction].map(m => {
          const angle = (m * 2 * Math.PI) / 9;
          const scale = (75 + 25 * Math.cos(angle)) / 100;
          const applystyle = {
            left: -75 + 150 * Math.sin(angle) + "px",
            transform: "scale(" + scale + ")",
            position: "absolute",
            "z-index": Math.floor(100 * scale)
          };
          return animate(
            this.timer / mov[direction].length + "ms",
            style(applystyle)
          );
        });

        //we create the animation with builder.build
        const myAnimation = this.builder.build(animations);

        //the animation is applied to the element
        this.player = myAnimation.create(item.nativeElement);

        //when finished, change the value of the array [0,2,7]
        this.player.onDone(
          () =>
            (this.animates[index] = mov[direction][mov[direction].length - 1])
        );
        this.player.play();
    });
  }
```

the [new stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-sqt1uq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

**Update 3***: To undestand the formulas, take paper and pencil and a use a few mathematics: Imagine a circunference with a radius "r". Draw a vertical line from the center and mark a point in the circunference.  Call "angle" to the angle in clockwise from the vertical to the line that join the point with the cencer of the circunference.

```
left=r*Math.sin(angle)-width_of_img/2
```

For the scale we need remember that when "angle" is 0 scale is 1, and when "angle" is 180 degrees scale is 0.5 (or another number between 1 and 0 -more less, more depth). Call "minScale" to this value. This mean that Math.cos(0)=1 scale is 1 and Math.cos(180degrees)=-1 scale is minScale. So

```
 scale=(1+minScale)/2+(1-minScale)/2*Math.cos(angle)
```

Answer (score 0):

As you're new to Angular, I suggest you a way to work with 3rd-party components:

1. Search for the Angular component that suite your need or Angular framework which has tools to help you build your component.
2. Import it to your project (use `npm install ...`). Normally almost 3rd-party components will guide you how to install itself.
3. Import the installed component to your project's `.module.ts` file then use it.

Comment: Could you tell me more about that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

this might help you

```
https://github.com/Wlada/angular-carousel-3d
```

If you use bower, just run bower install angular-carousel-3d. If not, download files angular-swipe.js, carousel-3d.css, and carouse3d.js from the following github repos :

```
Angular Swipe
Angular Carousel 3D
```

Note: you can download and use the minified versions as well.

Add theses files to your code:

```
<link href="carousel-3d.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="angular.js"></script>
<script src="angular-swipe.js"></script>
<script src="carousel-3d.js"></script>
```

Add the angular-carousel-3d module as a dependency to your application module:

```
angular.module('MyApp', ['angular-carousel-3d']);
```

In your template :
Add a carousel-3d attribute to any element.
Add ng-model with your array of objects
Add carousel3d-slide directive and ng-repeat to render slides

```
<div carousel3d ng-model="arrayOfObjects">
    <div carousel3d-slide ng-repeat="slide in app.slides track by $index">
        <figure>
            <img ng-src="{{slide.src}}" alt=""/>
            <figcaption ng-bind="slide.caption"></figcaption>
        </figure>
    </div>
</div>
```