# Carousel animation not running properly with real data

Tags: angular, angular-animations

Taking reference of this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66044499/need-to-pause-the-carousel-animation-regularly-and-call-a-function) , I implemented the animation but that was with the dummy data.

[image]

Now when the real data comes up (takes around a sec.), animation does not work properly and that is because the animation function is executed before the data comes:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.getData();
}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.calculateDimensions();
    this.animateCarousel();     // Animation Function
  }

  getData() {
    timer(1000).subscribe(res => {
      this.data = [
        {
          name: "Max",
          age: 27
        },
        ...
        ...
      ]
     });
  }
```

I tried to execute the animation function after the data comes, but that is also not working.

```
getData() {
    timer(1000).subscribe(res => { ...
    });
    this.calculateDimensions();
    this.animateCarousel();
}
```

Stackbliz [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-6qy1um?file=src/app/app.component.ts).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I was able to get it to work with your last attempt by simply wrapping the 2 methods in a setTimeout function for 100ms...

However, a better solution would be to listen for dom changes and detect when #card div is loaded...

https://nitayneeman.com/posts/listening-to-dom-changes-using-mutationobserver-in-angular/

Comment: Thanks. MutationObserver resolved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

First things first - the code you posted will not execute those actions after the data is supplied. For that to happen, they would need to be in the inner subscription, i.e. in the same scope where `this.data` is assigned.

Nonetheless, even if those methods were run after the `this.data` assignment, it would still produce the error.

Note that your `items` queries items with id `card`. Those items are based on your `data` property using `ngFor`. But the DOM elements are not generated right away, so at first your QueryList will be empty, even right after `this.data` has been assigned.

Luckily for you, the QueryList have a [changes](https://angular.io/api/core/QueryList#changes) property which emits each time its contents are changed. This means that you can subscribe to it and start your animation once the changes has been made, e.g.

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.items.changes.subscribe(x => {
      this.calculateDimensions();
      this.animateCarousel();
    });
  }
```

This way, those methods will be run each time the contents of your `data` is changed. Haven't looked deeper into your code - you might want to only run them after first change,  then you could do something like this:

```
this.items.changes
  .pipe(take(1))
  .subscribe(x => {
    this.calculateDimensions();
    this.animateCarousel();
  });
```